# Making a cpnode function?

Tags: c, debugging, nodes

I am trying to make a function that copies a node. I am trying to have the program on error or NULL return NULL, I can only have one return statement

I have the following code and I am not sure what else to do from here.. Any tips/advice I would greatly appreciate

```
Node *cpnode(Node *curNode)
{
      if (curNode == NULL) return NULL;
      Node *result = malloc(sizeof *result);
      result -> value = curNode -> value;
      result -> next = cpnode(curNode -> next;

return(result); 
}
```

EDIT:

I have edited my code when trying to compile I am getting errors such as
Node has no member named 'value' and 'next'. Why is that?

Also I know I can easily return NULL on my if statement and at the end return with my result but how could I just have only one return statement with NULL on error?

To define my Node would I have to do something like this:

```
Node *cpnode(Node *curNode)
{
  struct Node{
                 *result;
                 *value;
                 *next;
  }
  if (curNode == NULL) return NULL;
  Node *result = malloc(sizeof *result);
  result -> value = curNode -> value;
  result -> next = cpnode(curNode -> next;

  return(result); 
}
```

Comment: `new` is a C++ thing, use `Node *result = malloc(sizeof *result);`

Comment: @sss34  I have not understood what means "a function that copies a node when included in another program" .

Comment: `cpnode(curnode -> next`; --> `cpnode(curnode -> next);`

Comment: I have clarified my question more so and edited my code.

Comment: Did you defined `Node` type?....

Comment: BTW you function is recursive and endless.

Comment: @LPs -- so I have to have struct Node and list all my variables?

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: struct {
                          *value;
                           *result; 
                          }

Comment: @sss34 don't post edits in comment, edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your code: your Node structure isn't properly defined and you're using it as a type which you didn't `typedef`; your text talks about copying a node but your code copies a linked list of nodes; `result` doesn't seem like it should be part of the Node structure;  your code isn't syntactically correct (e.g. missing paren).

Here's a rework of your code into something that compiles and runs.  Since you didn't specify the type for `value`, I'm assuming it's a string below but you can change that to whatever you want:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Node
{
    char *value;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

Node *copyNodes(Node *currentNode)
{   
    Node *result = NULL;

    if (currentNode != NULL)
    {
        if ((result = malloc(sizeof *result)) != NULL)
        {
            result->value = currentNode->value;
            result->next = copyNodes(currentNode->next);
        }
    }

    return result; 
}

void freeNodes(Node *currentNode)
{
    if (currentNode != NULL)
    {
        if (currentNode->next != NULL)
        {
            freeNodes(currentNode->next);
            currentNode->next = NULL;
        }
    }
    free(currentNode);
}

int main()
{
    Node a, b;

    b.value = "last";
    b.next = NULL;

    a.value = "first";
    a.next = &b;

    Node *c = copyNodes(&a);

    printf("%s\n", c->next->value);

    freeNodes(c);

    return 0;
}
```

If we make a copy of all the nodes using `malloc()`, then when finished, we need to free all the copies in a similar fashion to how they were created.  That's what the function `freeNodes()` does.